# Getting data from database and storing it in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to get data from database using raw sql query and store it in a string so I could use it later or multiple times in the controller.

The way i did it,

```
var data=db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"select email from mail");
mail.To.Add(data);
```

gives this error message:

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection.Add(string)' has some invalid
>   arguments

Please help.

Thanks in advance
.

Comment: _says best overload method_ ???

Comment: `ExecuteSqlCommand` is for commands like `UPDATE` or `DELETE` that do not return results. If you want to read results you probably want `ExecuteReader`. Please read an ADO.NET tutorial; this is really basic stuff.

Comment: thanks for fast response but dear Dour High Arch there is no ExecuteReader

Comment: And this is the error message                                Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: You have not shown what is `sss` variable and what value it holds.

Comment: sorry for that i have changed it sss was actually data

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: when i run the code it says Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: You should be adding the error details to the original question, not to comments. If you write a good question you will get answer.

Comment: The error you see is self explanatory! The `ExecuteSqlCommand` returns an `int`. Your `Add` method expects a string(the email?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is self explanatory! The `ExecuteSqlCommand` methods returns an `int` value. So the type of `data` variable is `int`. You are trying to pass that int variable to the [`Add` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144695(v=vs.110).aspx) where it expects a `string` value.

If you are trying to get the Email column value from the mail table, you should consider using `SqlQuery` method.

```
var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(@"select email from mail").ToList();
```

This code execute the sql `select email from mail` and return a list of string (one string for each email from your SQL result set). That means the variable `data` is of type `List<string>`. You can loop through that collection and add each email (which is `string` type) to the `Add` method

```
foreach (var email in data)
{
    mail.To.Add(email);
}
```

Comment: Sorry sir but still same error my table only have one row

Comment: Are you saying, after trying the code i posted in the answer, you are still getting the compile error ! That is impossible! Double check your code with the code in the answer. Make sure you are using the correct variable in the Add (`email` which is the item in the loop)

Comment: yes here is the error Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: What are you passing to the Add method ? what is the type ? (Hover your cursor over the value you are passing to it and VS will show you the tool top with the type)

Comment: thank you very much sir your code worked with a little change i changed my query from select email from mail to select * from mail and it worked thank you very much for your fast response